# Average time between the decay of 2 atoms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, radioactivity, half-life

I want to calculate the average time ($\bar{t}$) between the decay of two atoms. These atoms are part of a larger number ($N_0$) atoms whose Half-life is $T$.

My idea: you can calculate $\bar{t}$ by dividing the total time $\tau$ it takes until every atom of $N_0$ is decayed with $N(\tau)$. Since with the Beer–Lambert-Law it takes and infinite time for everything to decay i need to use limits.

$\bar{t}=\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\frac{\tau}{N(\tau)}$ where $N(\tau)=N_0\cdot e^{-\frac{ln(2)}{T}\tau}$

because of $\lim_{\tau\to\infty}\bar{t}="\frac{\infty}{0}"$ you can use l'hospital and get $\bar{t}=\frac{1}{-\frac{ln(2)}{T}N_0}$

 since the time i get is negative its not right but i dont know where my mistake is. Is already my approach wrong ? Because

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule only applies to limits of the form $\frac\infty\infty$ or $\frac00$.

Comment: hmm. okay. is there maybe another way to calculate $\bar{t}$ ? I dont know how to deal with the fact that the time until the last atoms is decayed is $\infty$. i hope someone has an idea

Comment: It's a little unclear. Are talking about labeling 2 atoms, and then computing the average time between their decays, or are you talking about counting all the decays with a time tag $t_j$ for $j=1,\cdots N$, and then finding the average of $(t_{j+1}-t_j)$?

Comment: JEB- counting all the decays with a time tag tj for j=1,⋯N, and then finding the average of (tj+1−tj)

Comment: push***********